# How to use my ubuntu server as router?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, iptables, nat

```
                       +---+        
            eth1- *.1.6| S |           
              =========|   |           
                       |PC1|private net      --------------------
                       |   |==============|||PC 2 with eth0 *.0.7|||
                       | R |eth0-*.0.6       --------------------
                       +---+
```

eth1 = interface with internet
eth0 = interface private

eth1 and eth0 are two different network

I'd like to share my internet connection to my PC2. I guess it should work with some Iptables rules but doesn't work for me or I don't konw how to do it ...

here is my iptables on PC1:

---

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 789 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 789 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 218 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 60 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       2      158 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0



Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2796 packets, 273921 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3217 packets, 335744 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

---

I used this command ( sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE ) on my PC1

I tried lot of tutorial but PC2 can't get access to internet !

What can I do ? I'm completly stuck

Comment: Did you enable forwarding? `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` should give 1.

Comment: Yes Of course .

Comment: Please edit your question adding outputs from `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L` and `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L`. I don't think this `target prot opt source destination MASQUERADE all -- anywhere anywhere` is correct.

Comment: I changed my post with your 2 commands !!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Should be this:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me .. 
I can't ping internet from my PC 2

Comment: Show us. Try to ping internet for awhile from your PC2, and then do again the listings of the current iptables as before and edit them into your question.

Comment: I can ping eth0 and eth1 but I can't ping the gateway of eth1 from PC2 is it one of my problem?

Comment: So I did a traceroute from eth0 to 8.8.8.8 an it works but from PC2 it doesn't work.. I can't understand why ....any help .?

Comment: Please do as per my previous comment. I want to observe the packet counters in an attempt to understand where the packets are going.